# Handler for (null) returned invalid result code 70007 / causing error 500?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, 500-error

I am getting these errors on some pages in my site (php/apache/linux/mysql vps) on intervals and can't seem to find any reproducible scenario :

> Handler for (null) returned invalid
>   result code 70007
>
> or
>
> Handler for (null) returned invalid
>   result code 70014

It occurs mainly on pages where file (image) uploads are done. It then causes a 500 error.

Google hasn't returned anything conclusive, has anybody come across these errors ?

Comment: I have exacly the same problem, and also not reproducible, and neither client- nor php-script-specific. Thanks to @covener for the great explanation of the code-meanings. I want to add following: - it **ONLY** happens with **POST**-Inputs (either variables or file-transfers). My suspicion for a probable cause is - php Suhosin-Extension (e.g. html header filter)
- load-balancer
- internet-providers with poor transferrate/proxy Could this be further narrowed down?

Answer (score 3):

7 is "time up" and 14 is "EOF", so the root cause of this is probably a read timeout during the upload.

The 70000 prefix means they are APR status codes.

They are logged poorly here because they the core of apache is expecting a different type of error code then what is returned -- these are APR or "filter" return codes but the core of httpd is expecting a HTTP status code or 0 for OK.